# Typescript: Union type from array of objects

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to derive a union type from a property on an array of objects:

```
interface Tool {
  readonly id: string
}

const tools = [
  {id: "foo"},
  {id: "bar"},
] as const

function doTheThing<T extends typeof tools>(id: T[number]["id"]) {}

doTheThing("foo") // should work
doTheThing("baz") // should fail
```

This works ok in that the type is narrowed to `foo | bar` but what I really want is to type the tools object as well:

```
const tools: readonly Tool[] = [
  {id: "foo"},
  {id: "bar"},
] as const
```

This way I get type checking on both the tools object and the function. If I add the type to tools I no longer get the function argument narrowed correctly.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHt0BtkG8CwAUMslBHACbohYCeywFAXMgM5hSgDmRAvkUQTV2yMJiysWZStTppxAbQC6yALzIFRErkYsARDEx7eAGi15dyPQCM4UY2eIXmVgPp6TbdAFsIYABbc%20hASEMbIAPQRbP7oAK5YFMjwwDhgtAAOEAj%202QDWRCpwrMhCIOwChDBxIAhgwNTIVKi5LdwAPKjIEAAekCAUJelZ6DCi4qwAfAAUlqgKIHHe1tBKCnqMekoAlHj8hETNrYEgXNMGRrtRMfGJyADu6FAFhEcQbafntgBeelfRrFiCSSKTSmWyuQQeSAA)

Comment: The easiest way is probably to add an extra line `tools as readonly Tool[]`, that way you get the narrowed type, and if it doesn't match the interface, the cast will throw an error.

Comment: If I do that the `id` param to doTheThing gets widened to `string` so the bottom typecheck doesn't fail